# headerViewForSection isn't called

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates

I created a new Storyboard app, created an IBOutlet for my table, implemented the two table delegates.

```
@interface FirstViewController () <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>.
```

I also implemented the optional selector, "headerViewForSection":

```
- (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)headerViewForSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"called");
    //UITableViewHeaderFooterView* header =[self.testTable headerViewForSection:0];
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)];
    label.text = @"toast";
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:6];
    //[header addSubview:label];
    return label;
}
```

unfortunately, I never get a "called" in the console. I also tried to call this manually, but no success on that one.

Why isn't the function get called?

P.S, I added that in the constructor:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _testTable.delegate = self;
    _testTable.dataSource = self;
}
```

so I specified the delegate, I have no why why it's not working.

Comment: Where is the method name from? That is not the standard delegate method for handling the header view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That method is part of `UITableView` and is an internal method that the `UIViewController` doesn't need to go anywhere near.

I believe what you are looking for is the method...

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

which is part of `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: You need to change it to `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`. You need the whole thing and the correct return type. If it still isn't being then are you certain the delegates are being added correctly? Also, what is your code for the other delegate methods? (specifically `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;`